# Scroll snapping to nested components/elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

[image]

As you can see in the gif, I've got a large, scrollable container that has several main blocks ('Attack', 'Release', etc.) inside it.
Each of those main blocks has one or multiple columns (under attack 'Attack time', under Levels 'Threshold', 'Density', etc)

The HTML structure can be summarized as follows:

```
<div class="big-scrollable">
  <div class="main-block">
    <h4>Attack</h4>
    <div class="column-container">
      <div class="column">
        <!-- Attack time -->
        <... content ...>
      </div>
      <div class="column shown-when-expanded">
        <!-- Some other column -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-block>
    <h4>Release</h4>
    <div class="column-container">
      <div class="column">
        <!-- Release time -->
        ...
      </div>
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

I would like the big scrollable container to snap to each small column ('Attack time', 'Release time', 'Threshold', 'Density', etc).

I tried styling the elements this way:

```
.big-scrollable
{
  overflow-x: auto;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scroll-snap-type: x proximity;
}

.column
{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

But this doesn't work.
Is there any pure CSS solution to this? Or will I have to solve this with JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

The Codepen example provided by Jonas Weinhardt does work and seems to contain the same CSS.

I've provided a bit more of the code I'm using in the following Pastebin snippets. (Note that I changed the class names to make this question a bit clearer)

Important HTML: https://pastebin.com/DjvJt8v1

Important CSS: https://pastebin.com/tmLQQhbU

Comment: Can you provide a working example in e.g. jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer for this scenario

So after a bit of trying with the real css classes/html structure (pastbin links in the question) I figured it out what the problem is.
The `.big-scrollable` and `.column` classes T. J. Evers provided are correct and don't have to change for this to work. The main issue was that the `.column-container` class had a `overflow` property set as well wich broke the intended behaviour.

**So basically no children of your main scroll container (here: `.big-scrollable`) and your container you want to snap to (here: `.column`) can have a property of `overflow` set for this to work!**

(except `overflow: unset` of course)

Codepen with the html structure oft this question that works:
https://codepen.io/jonas_weinhardt/pen/mdmqypr

### First Answer (Can be ignored)

I did the following and it seems to work for me:

```
.big-scrollable{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.column{
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

Works with `scroll-snap-type: x proximity;` aswell if you like this behavior more.

Comment: Your codepen example works, but somehow it doesn't work in my environment. What does work, is when I put `scroll-snap-start` on the `.column-container` (but that's not what I want).

Somehow, the scroll snapping on `.column` just doesn't register. And I just need to know why. Is it some weird property of flex boxes or something...?

Comment: Can you maybe show me the `.big-scrollable` , `.column-container`  and `.column` classes that you are using?

Comment: I think so, but how would I go about doing that?

Comment: And the `.main-block` class would be nice to see if that is possible

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me those classes aswell?

Comment: I edited the question to include some more context.

Comment: I edited my Codepen and it looks like its working. The only really thing I did was to add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the `.settings-menu` class. Does it work for you if you do the same?

Comment: And remove the `overflow-x:scroll;` from the `.menu-columns` class. I Think this is where your code breaks!

Comment: Thou art right, adding `overflow: unset` to .settings-menu (only in this specific situation, it actually needs a scrollbar sometimes) fixes it! They don't even need ```flex-shrink: 0```

If you edit your answer to include that levels between `.big-scrollable` and `.column` cannot have `overflow: scroll`, the bounty is yours!

Comment: Im glad i could help you :D Edited my answer to describe the real problem.